# I am trying to use jasonp using javascript to display the data in it

Tags: javascript, jsonp

i've been trying to get data from the following [url](http://apps3.mcot.net/mcot_script/mcot_news_programs_all_in_cat.php?) but without any success. The following is the html code that i have got so far. I'm not sure why it is not working, could someone explain to me please.

```
<html>
    <button >  
        <h1 id="head">`Top News #1`</h1>  
    </button>  
    <script>
        function processJSON(text) 
        {
            document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = text[0].news_title;
        };   
    </script>    
    <script src='http://apps3.mcot.net/mcot_script/mcot_news_programs_all_in_cat.php?jsoncallback=processJSON'>   
    </script>   
</html>
```

Comment: the fact that the link does not produce the required call to `processJSON` may be a hint - look at the data that comes back in that script tag .. short version: `http://apps3.mcot.net/mcot_script/mcot_news_programs_all_in_cat.php` doesn't "do" JSONP

Comment: if you "control" the content of that external site - then you need to know, the issue is with the server side code

Comment: i see, but unluckily I'm not in control of the server

Comment: well, the only other solution is to use your server to make the request, and then you don't even have to use JSONP "cruft", just a plain ol' AJAX call required

Comment: i can see the data when i inspect sources though is there a way to get it from there?

Comment: i've tried ajax and it works with a CORS extension on chrome but the prob is that I'm developing a TV app and it doesn't work on that platform. haha thats why i'm avoiding ajax. Thanks anyways

Comment: yeah, that site doesn't do CORS, nor does it do JSONP - therefore you'll need to do the request through your server

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to parse it to json, try this:

```
var data= JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = data[0].news_title;
```